# angular.json to handle all kinds of hosts

Tags: angular, active-directory, openconnect, angular.json

i am using manfred steyer's  oidc oauth lib....there is a redirect url obviously pn AD...i have to configure angular.json or something that can handle all scenarios.ofcourse for local development i can set it to local host:4200 in architect/serve,...the redirect works locally....for the public redirect url,redirect is not working.  is there a way to handle all situations like both local n public facing urls..  or just have separate files for local and cloud?I AM looking at something like this

"serve": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
"options": {
"browserTarget": "project:build",
"host": "0.0.0.0"
"publichost": "public redirect url"
},
"

sorry if i missed something more simple. i am returning after a long break ...has been ages since i last did these or even saw AD/angular configs..